# Pandas Dataframe selecting a single value each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to have access to an element inside a panda dataframe, my df looks like below

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3, 2, 1 | 5, 6, 7 |
| 1 | 3, 2, 1 | 5, 6, 7 |
| 2 | 3, 2, 1 | 5, 6, 7 |

I want to print from A the second value for every index for example, the problem I don't know how to select them.

Output should be

```
(2,2,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "3, 2, 1" is a list, you can do this with :

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

if this is a string, you can do this with :

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split(", ")[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

If the entries in `A` are a non-string iterable (like a `list` or `tuple`, e.g.), you can use pandas string indexing:

```
df['A'].str[1]
```

Full example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> a = (3, 2, 1)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[a], [a], [a]], columns=['A'])
>>> df
           A
0  (3, 2, 1)
1  (3, 2, 1)
2  (3, 2, 1)

>>> df['A'].str[1]
0    2
1    2
2    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

If the entries are strings, you can use pandas string methods to split them into a list and apply the same approach above:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> a = '3,2,1'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[a], [a], [a]], columns=['A'])
>>> df
       A
0  3,2,1
1  3,2,1
2  3,2,1

>>> df['A'].str.split(',').str[1]
0    2
1    2
2    2
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: I have to thank! Thanks.  str[x] was the missing point.

Answer (score 1):

**If column A contain string values:**

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "A" :["3, 2, 1","3, 2, 1", "3, 2, 1"],
    "B" : ["5, 6, 7", "5, 6, 7", "5, 6, 7"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
output = df["A"].apply(lambda x:  (x.split(",")[1]).strip()).to_list()

print(output)
```

**Result:**

```
['2', '2', '2']
```